# Trying to apply_async celery task with mongodb ObjectId, get EncodeError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, celery, pickle

I have a Flask application (apache2 + mod_wsgi) with Celery and MongoDB. Celery is configured like this:

```
#foo.py
from celery import Celery
from celery.contrib.methods import task_method

celery = Celery('foo', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

class Foo:
...
    @celery.task(filter=task_method)
    def cel_task(self, object_id_str):
        ...
```

Before I start apache, I start Celery daemon with this command:

```
celery multi start worker -A foo
```

Then I start apache server. On post request to my server I call one of the foo method. Inside of this method the data related to this request is saved to MongoDB and then I am trying to call the celery task and pass it ObjectId (in string format) of previously inserted MongoDB document.

```
class foo:
    ...
    def handle_request(self, request):
        ...
        inserted_document = self.db.documents.insert_one(processed_request)
        self.cel_task.apply_async(args=[str(inserted_document.inserted_id)], eta=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=10))
```

And, finally, on the last line I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/application/flaskapp.py", line 21, in webhook_handler
    return foo.handle_request(request.get_json())
  File "/home/ubuntu/application/foo.py", line 71, in handle_request
    self.cel_task.apply_async(args=[str(inserted_document.inserted_id)], eta=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=10))
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 565, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 354, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 310, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 165, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 241, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/botenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 356, in pickle_dumps
    return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
EncodeError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed
```

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this as I have little experience with multithreading. Based on the error log, I had come to a conclusion this is somehow related with serialization. But the only argument I pass in apply_async to my celery task is ObjectId in string format (I used to pass it just as ObjectId, later changed it to string, but nothing changed). I thought that the problem is connected with the fact that I use class method instead of an ordinary function. But I tried a test class method task without MongoDB usage and it worked just fine.

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue ?. Even i am facing similar issue ?.

Comment: @sush As far as I remember, I gave up and moved my cel_task from the class, now it's an ordinary function outside of class definition.

Comment: @stainslav, i was able to fix the issue. not sure, how it works for you but i'll send you the instructions to fix.

Comment: Anyone solved this one?